# Add a number to id column which associated with specific strings in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to add a specific number (300 for example) to id that associated with specific strings in another column.

Table1

```
id  value     section_name
1   a.jpg     photo     
2   b         text
3   c.jpg     photo
```

here is what i want as result:

```
id      value     section_name
301     a.jpg     photo     
2       b         text
303     c.jpg     photo
```

Comment: Looks like a bad idea. But you can use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumin that id is not an auto increment and constrained  column  you can use and update  eg:

```
update my_table  
set id = id +300
where section_name ='photo'
```